# Загрузка русского шрифта в MINIX3

Tags: шрифты

Я изучаю MINIX3.2.1 Хочу чтобы русский шрифт подгружался и чтобы программы в которых есть русские символы были читабельны, в /home директории есть файл .ashrc прописал вот эту строчку loadfont /usr/lib/fonts/cp1251.fnt, но шрифт по прежнему не грузится, но если просто ввести эту команду то всё работает, подскажите пожалуйста в чём моя ошибка, спасибо заранее за ответ

Скорее как подключить эту команду в загрузку MINIX

Answer (score 0):

Значит почитав man loadfont. Понял что нужно переместить файл шрифта cp1251.fnt в /etc/font причём font это не папка, а файл того самого русского шрифта cp1251.fnt, просто скопируйте этот шрифт в /etc/ и переименовать нужно файл шрифта в font без всяких расширений потом shutdown и запуск системы. У меня всё заработало MINIX версии 3.2.1 под VirtualBox 5.2.6